# Counting command (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

Im trying make the bot count to whatever the user says but it is not sending anything

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.command()
async def count(ctx, num):
  for i in range(1, num+1):
    await ctx.channel.send(i)
```

There is no error.
Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that num has to be an integer. Here's how you should do it :-

```
@client.command()
async def count(ctx, num: int):
  for i in range(1, num+1):
    await ctx.send(i)
```

Comment: Type hints are only suggestions. They do not force a variable to be of a certain type.

Comment: @Benjin They are not just suggestions in discord.py. Read about the [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) and cancel your downvote.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that `discord.py` attempts conversion and raises errors when it can't with type hints and converters.

Comment: ok i have fixed it thanks